# É possível passar um método como parâmetro para ser executado numa thread?

Tags: java, thread, parâmetros, método

Tenho uma aplicação onde cada processo é chamado por um único método e esse processo precisa ser executado em uma thread.
O código das threads é idêntica em todos, mudando apenas o conteúdo do método **run**().
Não gostaria de ficar copiando e colando dezenas de vezes o mesmo código.
É possível fazer algo parecido com o exemplo abaixo?

```
public void metodoComThread(? metodoPassadoComoParametro) //<-- Aqui passei o método!
{ 
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                metodoPassadoComoParametro(); // <-- executando o método passado como parâmetro
            }
        });

        t.start();

        while (t.isAlive()) {
            try {
                //...
                // faz alguma coisa, atualiza um progressbar, etc
                //...

                Thread.sleep(100);              
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: O tipo de comportamento que você está tentando obter (atualizar um progressbar durante a execução de uma tarefa em segundo plano) me sugere que você deveria tentar usar `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @Piovezan , era só um exemplo. Mas valeu pela dica! Mais um aprendizado!

Comment: Bom, em Delphi (que é minha área), tem como você mandar um método anonimo. Acredito que em Java, tenha algo semelhante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você o que precisa é de passar um objecto de uma classe que implemente a interface *Runnable*.

Declare uma classe que implemente *Runnable* por cada uma das tarefas que quer executar:

```
public class Tarefa1 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //código para executar a tarefa1
    }
}

public class Tarefa2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //código para executar a tarefa2
    }
}
```

Estas classes substituem aquilo a que você chamou de "metodoPassadoComoParametro"

Altere o método `metodoComThread()` assim:

```
public void metodoComThread(Runnable tarefa) //Aqui passei a tarefa a executar
{ 
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread(tarefa);

        t.start();

        while (t.isAlive()) {
            try {
                //...
                // faz alguma coisa, atualiza um progressbar, etc
                //...

                Thread.sleep(100);              
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Quando quiser executar uma determinada tarefa, chame o método assim:

```
metodoComThread(new Tarefa1());
```

Se não quiser ter as classes declaradas à partida, pode criá-las ao chamar o método:

```
metodoComThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            // código a executar
        }
    });
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ramaral!  Assim que testar eu já te dou um feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar as referências a métodos que existem no Java 8 em diante.

Por exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public void metodo1() {
        System.out.println("Metodo 1");
    }

    public void metodo2() {
        System.out.println("Metodo 2");
    }

    public boolean metodoComThread(Runnable metodoPassadoComoParametro) { 
        try {
            Thread t = new Thread(metodoPassadoComoParametro);
            t.start();

            while (t.isAlive()) {
                try {
                    //...
                    // faz alguma coisa, atualiza um progressbar, etc
                    //...

                    Thread.sleep(100);              
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinhaClasse mc = new MinhaClasse();
        mc.metodoComThread(mc::metodo1);
        mc.metodoComThread(mc::metodo2);
    }
}
```

Observe que o parâmetro do método `metodoComThread` é do tipo `Runnable`. A interface `Runnable` é uma interface funcional, pois só possui um único método abstrato. O método em questão da interface `Runnable` é o `run`, que não tem parâmetros e tem retorno `void`. Vez que os métodos `metodo1` e `metodo2` também não têm parâmetros e também são `void`, então eles são compatíveis com `Runnable`.

Comment: Estou implementando no Android Studio. Não sei se ele suporta essa versão do Java.  Tentei rodar aqui, ele sugeriu que eu modificasse a versão do JAVA na IDE, mas deu alguns erros estranhos.  Mas sua resposta ao meu ver é valida. Só não pude testar.

Comment: @AlexQL Veja isso: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: Obrigado! Vou tentar novamente. Minha aplicação precisa rodar com versão de, no mínimo, Android 4.0. Vamos ver esse j8-jack funciona nessa versão.